# How to troubleshoot NIntegrate non-numerical error?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, parametric-functions

I am trying to evaluate a 2d integral (denoted as `x` and `y` here) with a function that involves a numerical integral at each point.

Currently I have the following code

```
auxiliary[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[- (Log[u]/Sqrt[1 - u^2])
     Exp[(2 u)/(1 + u) *x* y -  (u^2)/(1 - u^2) (x - y)^2], {u, 0, 1}]

intme[x_, y_] := Exp[- (x^2 + y^2)]/(2 \[Pi])*auxiliary[x, y]

Integrate[intme[x, y], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

The `?NumericQ` check for the auxiliary function was taken already from this forum's different answers, but it does not seem to solve the issue - Mathematica still returns the error message

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand -((E^(-((u^2 (x-y)^2)/(1-Power[<<2>>]))+(2 u x y)/(1+u)) Log[u])/Sqrt[1-u^2]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.
```

Is it because the function actually evaluates to non-numerical values somewhere? I tried to check some seemingly challenging cases by hand but I always get reasonable values. I get the same error message if I try to restrict the integral around zero with

```
Integrate[intme[x, y], {x, -0.1 , 0.1}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

Is there a way to find out whether my integral truly evaluates to non-numerical values, and how do I actually approximate such an integral if it does?

Edit: I am not sure whether this is relevant, but I can evaluate the integral without any extra settings with `SciPy` in Python - so I have faith it should be solvable in Mathematica too somehow.

Comment: I think you should put `?NumericQ` also in the definition of `intme`

Comment: To my understanding, this condition is only required for the parts that might happen to be undefined, and `intme` only contains an exponential function, so I didn't think it would be relevant there. In fact, adding it changes nothing.

Comment: Why didn't you use `NIntegrate[intme[x, y],...]`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `NIntegrate`instead of `Integrate`:

```
NIntegrate[intme[x, y], {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 0,Infinity}] 
(* 0.5 *)
```